# Bootstrap Tooltip - Not working - At wits end

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I can't for the life of me determine why the following does not work.  Any help would be appreciated. I've already sourced the StackOverflow areas for this and attempted some of the solutions, but I just can't see to make tooltips work correctly. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>

        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="well">
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
                <p>This is a test <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title"Some title" class="submit-tooltip">hover here</a>.</p>
        </div></div>

        <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.submit-tooltip').tooltip();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're lacking an ``=`` in your ``a`` tag

Answer (score 1):

What's not working?

First off, you are not closing the title tag => title="something"

Secondly, did you try loading the script tags in head? There are quite a few errors, but check out the fiddle.

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.submit-tooltip').tooltip();
    </script>
```

Edit : http://jsfiddle.net/BBYYz/

Comment: I have fixed the missing "=" in the title attribute for the 'a' tag.

Yes, I tried the loading of the script tag in the head as well.  I've read it should go in the foot, so that all assets are loaded by the time the script is processed.

No change on the results, so far...

Comment: To answer the question of what is not working... the tooltip is not displayed as demonstrated on the bootstrap web site.  That is, there is no little black balloon that appears above the linked text. A "normal" tooltip eventually shows up, but it's not what I'm expecting or wanting.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Loading the additional library was required. However I am 100% sure I read that the bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js files included all of the additional plugins...

From the bootstrap documentation: "Plugins can be included individually (though some have required dependencies), or all at once. Both bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js contain all plugins in a single file."

If that's the case, why do we need to include them additionally?

Comment: You don't need the additional library, you have to check for document.ready, which you didn't. http://jsfiddle.net/BBYYz/1/

Comment: An important note here that I learned while moving this solution to my larger project file: the inclusion of the jquery script needs to precede the inclusion of the bootstrap script.